# Migrating from CoffeeScript to es6

Tags: coffeescript, migration, ecmascript-6

I'd like to migrate a largish program from CoffeeScript to es6.  By largish I mean  3K lines of Coffee (1.9K w/o comments) -> 4.5K es5 w/o comments. Coffee is quite terse!

I realize I can just compile to es5 and upgrade by hand to es6 features.  But CS is more like es6 than es5 so would prefer migrating from CS, not es5. I'll use Traceur or 6to5 for es6 features not available yet.

Any pointers? I've seen one [discussion on AirPair](https://www.airpair.com/coffeescript/posts/migrating-coffeescript-to-es6-javascript) but it was quite incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

There is a work in progress library to automate the process: https://github.com/eventualbuddha/decaffeinate

This is still incomplete but maybe it could be a good starting point.